# _locale_import_po passing in a file

Tags: files, i18n-l10n

I am trying to use [_locale_import_po($file, $langcode, $mode, $group = NULL)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!locale.inc/function/_locale_import_po/7).  I want to point it to a local file in my Drupal site (e.g. drupal-7.23.fr.po').

However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

> fopen(): Filename cannot be empty locale.inc:693

I am using the following code to initialize the `$file` variable passed to the function.

```
  $file = new stdClass();
  $file->filename = 'drupal-7.23.fr.po';
  $file->filepath = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/'. $file->filename;
```

I have the file in sites/all/modules/mymodule/drupal-7.23.fr.po.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 693 of locale.inc is

```
$fd = fopen($file->uri, 'rb');
```

So you need to provide your file path on the `uri` member of the file object, instead of/in addition to `filepath`.

There are a bunch of different things done with that file object throughout the process you're calling, so there may be more you need to add as well.